# Set button image as selected image from library in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, image, button

I am making an app where I select a button, and it leads me to the Library to select a picture. I want that selected picture to become the main image of the button.
Can anybody help me?

Here is the code that I used to reach into the library:

```
- (IBAction)image1Pressed:(id)sender {

if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
    UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary])
{
    UIImagePickerController *picker1= [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    picker1.delegate = self;
    picker1.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self presentViewController:picker1 animated:YES completion:nil];
    [picker1 release];
}
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an outlet for the button, let's name it "imageButton". The let the image picker do the rest:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
UIImage *btnImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [imageButton setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Done.

Comment: Do I still need to keep the IBAction *image1Pressed connected?